# Strategy for spreading image downloads across domains?

Tags: browser, download, google-visualization

I am working on PHP wrapper for Google Image Charts API service. It supports serving images from multiple domains, such as:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com
http://0.chart.googleapis.com
http://1.chart.googleapis.com
...
```

Numeric range is 0-9, so 11 domains available in total.

I want to automatically track count of images generated and rotate domains for best performance in browser. However Google itself only [vaguely recommends](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html#enhancements):

> ...you should only need this if you're loading perhaps five or more charts on a page.

- What should be my strategy? Should I just change domain every N images and what would good N value be in context of modern browsers?
- Is there point where it would make sense to reuse domain rather than introduce new one (to save DNS lookup)?

I don't have specific number of images in mind - since this is open source and publicly available code I would like to implement generic solution, rather than optimize for my specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerations:

- Is the one host faster than the other?
- Does a browser limit connection per host?
- How long does it take for the browser to resolve a DNS name?

As you want this to make a component, I'd suggest you make it able to have multiple strategies to find the host name to use. This will not only allow you to have different strategies but also to test them against each other.

Also you might want to add support for the javascript libraries that can render the data on the page in the future so you might want to stay modular anyway.

Variants:

1. Pick one domain name and stick with it, hardcoded: `http://chart.googleapis.com`
2. Pick one domain name out of many, stick with it: e.g. `http://#.chart.googleapis.com`
3. Like 2 but start to rotate the name after some images.
4. Like 3 but add some javascript chunk at the end of the page that will resolve the DNS of the missing hostnames in the background so that it's cached for the next request (Provide the data of the hostnames not used so far).

Then you can make your library configureable, so you don't need to hardencode in the code the values but you provide the default configuration.

Then you can add the strategy as configuration so someone who implements can decide over it.

Then you can make the component offer to load the configuration from outside, so let's say, if you create a Wordpress plugin, the plugin can store the configuration and offer a plugin user an admin-interface to change the settings.

As the configuration already includes which strategy to follow you have completely given the responsibility to the consumer of the component and you can more easily integrate different usage-scenarios for different websites or applications.

Comment: On considerations (1) I would imagine these hosts are aliases and equal in performance (2) I know browser do limit, but don't know what is practical generic limit to go by (which is part of question) (3) I would think that would fluctuate wildly depending on environment, but it's safe to assume it takes _some_ (as in non-zero) time to resolve previously unknown domain.

Comment: **EDIT:** (1) Sound. (2) Per RFC 2 concurrent connections per hostname, browsers normally do more and other type of connections nowadays, see [Parallelize downloads across hostnames](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#ParallelizeDownloads). (3) See [Minimize DNS lookups](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#MinimizeDNSLookups)

Comment: Based on those articles and your answer I went with configurable options that default to change domain every 6 images and only rotate through 3 domains.

Comment: DNS lookup takes it's time. Just wanted to note that. It's what I knew , but preferred to link the google docs as they are working quite scientifically. An exemplary DNS lookup-time on a current windows XP workstation (which uses the underlying windows API) is about 250-500 millisecs, so half a second per hostname. The WAN connection is quite well, some other sources speak about 2-3 seconds even. You might want to consider to offer some interface that frontend generators can "cache" the DNS resolution for all hosts in question (regarding variant 4.).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand the request to rotate domains. I guess it does make sense in the context that your browser may only allow X open requests to a given domain at once, so if you have 10 images served from chart.googleapis.com, you may need to wait for the first to finish downloading before beginning to recieve the fifth, and so on.

The problem with rotating domains randomly is that then you defeat browser caching entirely. If an image is served from 1.chart.googleapis.com on one page load and then from 7.chart.googleapis.com on the next page load, the cached chart is invalidated and the user needs to wait for it to be requested, generated, and downloaded all over again.

The best solution I can think of is somehow determining the domain to request from algorithmically from the request. If its in a function, you can md5 the arguments somehow, convert to an integer, and then serve the image from `{$result % 10}.chart.googleapis.com`.

Probably a little overkill, but you at least can guarantee that a given image will always be served from the same server.

Comment: Precisely - the idea is to bypass connection limit and make browser download in paralles from different domains. I concur that random doesn't seem like a good idea. Logic should be persistent so that same images, generated in same order would get same URLs each time. Checksum is little random and leaving it to chance, posisbly making things worse... There is probably no point in having 10 images spread over 10 domains - loss from DNS lookups might be more than gain from domain spread.

Comment: True. I don't think any modern browser defaults have a comcurrent request limit lower than 4, so maybe a better way would be to keep a static counter and serve the first 4 charts from one domain, then move on through the domains that way.